# Why doesn't the page's width decrease according to viewport?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to accomodate a really really old website to mobile standards and for some reason it doesn't get a width of 320 or whatever pixel width when i activate the responsive view in chrome dev tools. The result of this makes the pixels small while still maintaining the original 900 px width (in the original pc version that's the fixed size according to which the site was built on)

This would be my media query CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

    body * {
        width: auto;
    }

    #container,
    #header,
    #nav,
    #container #wrapper,
    #content,
    #sidebar,
    #wrapper-bottom,
    #footer,
    #footer-inner,
    #footer-content
    {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        float: none;
    }

    /* Header
    -------------------------------------------------------------------*/   

    #header h1{
        display: block;

        text-align: center;
    }

    #header #search{
        position: static;
        display: block;
    }


    /* Navigation
    -------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    #nav ul{
        position: static;
    }



}
```

Comment: Have you added meta tag in head tag?

Comment: I pretty much didn't. I didn't know this was a thing and the site is like, ancient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use meta viewport along with your CSS. Something like this by instance :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need more are viewing into the mobile device and media query is not working then please check the meta tag in head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're viewing on your PC remove the word `device` from `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`.

In addition, make sure to use the meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that some element on the page has a fixed width that doesn't allow for the page to resize as desired. You need to go through the elements and find it. I've ran across this issue on several sites.